# Providing Google service account credentials manually in Golang

Tags: authentication, go, proxy, google-cloud-platform

To remotely connect to a Google-cloud Mysql database via the Go Proxy library, I need to provide service account credentials. This can be done through setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, but since I want the application to be able to run on different machines without having to set the environment variable everywhere, that is not an option.

As a result, I have to provide the service account credentials manually to my Golang application. The code below (without the authentication) gives this error message:

> default proxy initialization failed; consider calling proxy.Init explicitly: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

Google provides elaborate documentation on how to fix the manual authentication for a number of programming languages, but not for Go:

> https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-explicit-csharp

Could anyone help me out with setting authentication credentials manually in Golang?

Thanks a bunch!

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/mysql"
)

var db *sql.DB

func main() {

cfg := mysql.Cfg("mysql", "********", "********") //name , username, password
cfg.DBName = "MyDBName"
db := mysql.DialCfg(cfg)
defer db.Close()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `cloudsql-proxy` package, you're not directly connecting to your cloud SQL instance, but creating a [proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy) and connecting to it. It's the proxy connection where you have to provide the credentials.

In the tests for the cloud-sql package there is an example of [how to init the proxy with credentials](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/blob/master/tests/dialers_test.go#L63).

The proxy [initializes by itself](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/blob/master/proxy/dialers/mysql/hook.go#L29) if you don't do it manually, but you can call [`proxy.Init`](https://godoc.org/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/proxy#Init) with an http client, and you can create an http client with credentials.

I've not tested this, but you could try something like `proxy.Init(oauth2.NewClient(ctx, oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&oauth2.Token{AccessToken: <YOUR_TOKEN>})), nil, nil)` before the `DialCfg` call.

A better example, if you provide your credentials file (so it's not hard-coded) would be something like:

```
func main()
  credsFile := "path/to/your/credentials.json"
  SQLScope := "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin"
  ctx := context.Background()

  creds, err := ioutil.ReadFile(credsFile)
  if err != nil {
    # handle error
  }

  cfg, err := goauth.JWTConfigFromJSON(creds, SQLScope)
  if err != nil {
    # handle error
  }

  client := cfg.Client(ctx)
  proxy.Init(client, nil, nil)

  var db *sql.DB

  cfg := mysql.Cfg("mysql", "********", "********") //name , username, password
  cfg.DBName = "MyDBName"
  db, err := mysql.DialCfg(cfg)
  if err != nil {
    # handle error
  }
  defer db.Close()

  # your calls to cloudSQL

}
```

(This is mainly a copy of [the tests on that package](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/blob/master/tests/dialers_test.go).)